# How to apply a dusty texture on a photo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

I found this example photos in [Noel Shiveley](https://www.instagram.com/noeltheartist) 's Instagram

I wonder, how he applied this technique? What is the white noise called? Dust? Old Paper? Where I can find or create it?

And how to apply to photo?
I mean which blend option? Softlight? Mutiply? Screen?

By the way, what is this font name or style? hand drawing?

[image]
[image]
[image: lorm ipsum]
[image: lorem ipsum]

Comment: Related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/108295/overlay-to-make-image-look-dusty-with-fragmented-text/108850#108850

Answer (score 3):

In the images of the example, not only is the texture added but also adjustments in the background photos with some filters.

Original image from [unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/photos/ZkC0lNON4B4)

[image: Original image]

Filters: Fragment, Gaussian Blur, Opacity 60% (over a white background):

[image: Filters]

Texture: Dag Texture from [wikimedia.com](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dag_Texture_1_(Optical_Flare).png)

[image]

To the texture:

- If it's a color texture Menu Image → Adjustments → Desaturate
- Auto Levels
- Blend mode Screen, opacity 50%
- Reduce the shadows using the Levels Panel

[image: End]

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to get this look. Instagram uses a predifined filter, but you can also do it "manually" in photoshop. Try for example:
`->Filters -> Noise -> Dust and Scratches` and you can play with the settings.

For more of an in-depth analysis of what Instagram does, [here is a description and some tutorials for various retro effects](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/visuals/recreating-instagrams-retro-filter-effects/).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the "lint" you will see that it is the exact same texture in every photo.

The most common way to get this `overlay` to happen is to create a `mask` which is used to allow color in some areas and block out color in other areas. In the real world one might use a stencil and masking tape. In the digital world, it is achieved by using a special `layer mask` which contains a greyscale image (aka a black and white image).

While there are dust and scratch filters for this sort of thing, if you were sweep some dirt off the floor, sprinkle it onto a white piece of paper, then place the paper in direct sunlight and snap a close-up photo of it, you would have the basis for making a mask.

You would convert the color to greyscale, play with brightness and contrast, and paste it into the layer mask channel for a white layer.

The image would be on a layer below this.