# Easier or smarter method to apply a texture over multiple layered parts of an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask, texture, clipping-mask

Because I don't have the artistic talent needed, I often Google random images with the overall shape I need/want and modify it by recolouring or by applying "textures" — quotes because I'm using this term very loosely.

I usually simply make the selection and Clip the texture or apply a Mask (Picture #2), easy, peasy. However, this time, the image I've picked has a noticeable difference (you'll see below) and the way I've been doing so far would reduce the significance of the whole picture.

This is the original image:

[image: Original Image]

And when I tried to change the Parchment texture using the first method I've learned I've got this:

[image: Method #1]

[image: Result #1]

The left/right rolls don't exist anymore.

Then, thinking I could recreate the Inner and the Outer Shadows, I spliced all four parts of the image (left and right rolls, the main parchment and the four... handles?) but the only way I managed to apply the texture -AND- have the Layers Effects was this:

[image: Method #2]

If you notice the Group Layers names, I'm still not quite satisfied with the results of this texture in particular (and I have like 8 more Layer Groups hidden from these screenshots) and having to duplicate the texture and the Layers Effects 3 times for every new texture I find, although easy, is not very practical.

And so I'm here, hoping to find if there's an easier or at least a smarter way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Have you tried making an action?

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/108295/overlay-to-make-image-look-dusty-with-fragmented-text/108850#108850

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Place the *texture layer* with the area to be filled masked on top of the original image.
- Duplicate the original image as a new layer, place it above the *texture layer* and desaturate it: menu Image > Adjustments > Desaturate
- Change the *desaturated layer* blend mode to Multiply or Linear Burn and reduce the opacity
- Modify the *desaturated layer* levels if necessary

[image]

Comment: Geez! I kind of managed an alternative solution using Layer Groups right after posting but this is MUCH easier. I suppose that applying Levels is to counteract textures like [this one](https://postimg.cc/PvPpvvpz) that's "too whiteish" to right, am I correct?

Comment: With levels you can adjust lights, shadows and midtones to make them darker or lighter, it doesn't has to be always lighter.

Comment: I see, well, that really helped. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @Danielillo My compliments for your answer and for the animation.