# How to Achieve Very Realistic Grunge Textures

Tags: photoshop-effects

[image]

I was wondering how to achieve the type of super realistic grunge effect as in the canvas in the photo. Would it be a mixture of finding intricate patterns online and "compositing" them using blending modes? Or it it perhaps an action/preset pack they have downloaded and adapted?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Possibly helpful: [7,260,000 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=Photoshop+grunge+tutorial&hl=en&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit2v-ioM7gAhWHiVQKHUlXBXgQ_AUICSgA&biw=1410&bih=1232&dpr=1)

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE** - please look around a bit [tour] to get a sense of our community. Please also look carefully at [ask] and [answer] a question, in order to learn how best to frame queries for best results, and what to expect from answers. Whilst you're getting acquainted with us, take a peek also at [help/behavior] to get a feel for our community's behavioural expectations. Your question as initially framed is both very broad and only a tiny step away from a tutorial request, which we tend to frown on. Can you refine your question after reading [ask]?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there are several methods.

1. Take a photo of a real texture, and old wall, some cracked street, etc, and use it as a texture to mask or to overlay. [Overlay to make image look dusty with fragmented text](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/108295/overlay-to-make-image-look-dusty-with-fragmented-text/108850#108850)
2. Combine different generated textures, use programs like Paint.net or PhotoPaint to create them. (see the other answer in that same question) You can also look for some fractal generators. There are some that are suitable for a grudge look.
3. Use a node-based program like https://filterforge.com/filters/8879.html It basically does similar things but in a more controlled way.

   Probably the most well-known program is this: https://www.allegorithmic.com/products/substance-designer

   This is also a good one:http://spiralgraphics.biz/gen2tour/index.htm

   A free one: http://www.pixaflux.com/videos.php
4. Take some brushes and start painting and scratching... There are some good programs to make digital paint, like Corel Painter. Use dry brushes. This will take some time.
5. Download some textures from the internet and use them as my example 1.