# How to achieve rough degraded edges?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture, noise

[image: event poster for reference]

I have tried torn edges amongst other filters in the photoshop gallery however I can not achieve the inconsistent degraded edges as seen on the poster. Is this manually done?

Comment: Maybe its scanned?

Comment: I think some analogue technique was involved. Like printing and scanning again. It's not as old as the printing technique it tries to fake I think. Still it *could* be done in Photoshop. What do you need it for? Just to display on screen or is it for print?

Comment: Take a look a this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/108295/overlay-to-make-image-look-dusty-with-fragmented-text/108850#108850 you can have a similar effect playing with some values.

Comment: Print it.. photocopy it.. then photocopy the photocopy... repeat until it looks like you want.. scan that.

Comment: I presume older scanners would work better to degrade the overall image?