# Create grainy photocopy effect photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, creative-cloud

I am trying to imitate the grainy photocopy effect in the poster below. I have found some photoshop tutorials but it doesn't quite give me the exact outcome. I am using the beginning of the video tutorial below. Its a lot lengthier of a process than I thought. A lot of fiddling around.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZcrslJfVEs&t=106s

[image]

So far I have created the below following the beginning of the video tutorial which used the threshold to give a posterised effect and I settled for that as the closest I could get. I inverted it because I thought it looked better for the photo. But as you can see looked nothing like the above reference point. There is more grain in it.

Before and after

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overlay to make image look dusty with fragmented text](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/108295/overlay-to-make-image-look-dusty-with-fragmented-text) The first part of my answer covers the grainy text. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/108295/overlay-to-make-image-look-dusty-with-fragmented-text/108850#108850

Comment: The "duplicates" have also other goals which can make extracting the kernel of the effect difficult. Your case is halftoning with grains (=noise). A narrow grayscale range in a Black and white image really can get the wanted halftone pattern if the image is grainy and the image is tresholded with treshold or preferably curves adjustment layer. A slight slope in the curve is useful. An example (just adding noise) https://i.stack.imgur.com/52u2i.png It's very sensitive to image contrast, treshold and the amount of noise, only a part of the brightness range gets grays.